# Start profile button not enabled for .net core mvc application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, redgate, red-gate-ants, ants

I would like to profile the .net core web application using Ants profiler. Please see the below snapshot where the 'Start button' profile is not being enabled.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed today that .net core assembly field is required so provided the csproj file path.
Like in the below snapshot. Then it would enable "Start profile".

[image]

Credit: https://documentation.red-gate.com/app10/setting-up-and-running-a-profiling-session/choosing-application-types-and-settings/profiling-net-core-applications